# Minimal examples with external .vue component files not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, systemjs, jspm

I am starting with the snippets in this question [*How to use multiple vue components on single page?*](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-multiple-vue-components-on-single-page/10559?u=ziyuang) The following example works with `vue build app.vue`, but it does not work if I set up a simplest server and visit `index.html`.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    System.import('app.js');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'

window.onload = function() {
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      render: h => h(app)
    })
}
```

`app.vue`:

```
<template>
<qwop></qwop>
</template>

<script>

import qwop from 'qwop.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        'qwop': qwop
    }
}

</script>
```

`qwop.vue`:

```
<template>
<div>Hello</div>
</template>
```

Through running `vue build app.vue`, a web server is launched and I can see "Hello" in the web page. But nothing shows if I create a web server by for example `python -m http.server` and visit `index.html`. Anything wrong with my `index.html` and `app.js`?

Comment: did you import `app.vue` in `app.js` file ? also I doubt that `import` declarations work in files served by python server.

Comment: @SrinivasDamam Adding an `import app from 'app.vue'` in `app.js` will make SystemJS complain about an illegal `<` token, which should be from the first character of `app.vue`.